# Azure DocumentDB Users in a multi tenant application

Tags: azure-active-directory, multi-tenant, azure-cosmosdb

I am playing around with the Azure Document DB because we are planning to create a multi tenant application.

For the multi tenant application, my idea would be to create 1 db user per tenant. This gives me the advantage that tenant data would be completely separated: When creating a document, a permission is added to the tenant user. (Read/Write) This means when querying, the data will always be scoped to the current tenant.

I was also playing around with 1 DB user per end-user. But this gives me a lot of overhead to manage the security on documents. When user x from tenant z adds a document, all users from tenant z need to be updated with an extra permissions for that document. This seems unfeasible.

Is my assumption correct? Or would you suggest another approach for this? Are there any downside to this approach?

Answer (score 2):

For our multi-tenant solution we chose to not use DocumentDB's controls at all and do all of our authorization in the middle tier mostly because we wanted it to be predicate based and different per tenant. That said, your approach of using DocumentDB's authorization capabilities at the tenant level makes sense. That will give your tenants added assurance that other tenants can't see their data.

My one thought is that if you have some cross-tenant functionality (maybe in the form of tenant groups) then it would break the model so you may want to consider that.

I assume tenants are hundreds and users are thousands but whatever they are, you should confirm that the DocumentDB authorization capability scales to that level. Maybe one of the DocumentDB product managers that monitor this can chime in?

Comment: The users and permissions functionality in DocumentDB is intended to grant direct access to the database for a set of fine-grained resources. The resource tokens generated from creating a permission are temporary - similar to how OATH tokens behave. If you are looking to grant users direct access to your database endpoint for a set of resources, this is a great fit for you. If you are simply looking to isolate tenants for an application - performing this at the middle tier will be a lot easier.